# How to Pass Value from a login Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello I need help please
I am creating my first asp mvc Webpage.
I created a login and registration page connected with database.

I want to pass CustomerId from the customer that logged in to a Bookings table
So that it shows bookings related to that customer only. 
Bookings table has CustomerId as a foreign key. This is what I have done so far.

```
public class BookingController : Controller
{
    // GET: Booking
    public ActionResult Index(int customerId)
    {

        TravelExpertsEntities bookingdb = new TravelExpertsEntities();
        List<Booking> bookings = bookingdb.Bookings.Where(book => 
book.CustomerId == customerId).ToList();
        return View(bookings);
    }
}
}

//This is from login Controller 

 public ActionResult Login(Customer reg)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var details = (from userlist in db.Customers
                           where userlist.UserName == reg.UserName && 
      userlist.Password == reg.Password
                           select new
                           {
                               userlist.CustomerId,
                               userlist.UserName
                           }).ToList();
            if (details.FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                Session["CustomerId"] = 
      details.FirstOrDefault().CustomerId;
                Session["Username"] = details.FirstOrDefault().UserName;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Booking");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid UserName or Password");
        }
        return View(reg);
    }
```

I was able to pull all bookings but I want to filter it with the Customer that logged in.

Comment: You can pass the parameter as follows,
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Booking", new { customerId = details.FirstOrDefault().CustomerId });

Comment: Thank you Sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your RedirectToAction as below, to pass customerId as parameter

```
var CustomerIdparam=details.FirstOrDefault().CustomerId;
RedirectToAction("Index", "Booking", new{customerId=CustomerIdparam});
```

Comment: @Mann You are new to stack overflow that's why I am suggesting you, if it solved your problem then click on the check sign on situated left to the answer.